# how to remove duplicate JSON object in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, duplicates

I want to delete object containing duplicate 'file_url' from JSON file. like this.

```
{
    "0": {
        "file_url": "apple",
        "name": "apple.jpg"
    },
    "1": {
        "file_url": "dog",
        "name": "dog.jpg"
    },
    "2": {
        "file_url": "apple",
        "name": "apple.jpg"
    },
    "3": {
        "file_url": "cat",
        "name": "cat.jpg"
    },
    "4": {
        "file_url": "tiger",
        "name": "tiger.jpg"
    }
}
```

This is my json file. and number 0 and 2 are same things. so, I'd like to delete one of them and sort it out with a new index. like this:

```
{
    "0": {
        "file_url": "apple",
        "name": "apple.jpg"
    },
    "1": {
        "file_url": "dog",
        "name": "dog.jpg"
    },
    "2": {
        "file_url": "cat",
        "name": "cat.jpg"
    },
    "3": {
        "file_url": "tiger",
        "name": "tiger.jpg"
    }
}
```

I looked up several documents, but didn't work. I'm using Python 3.6 and I want help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this probably isn't effecient, but you could check each element of the second array against each element of the first array. each time you get element[i]==element[x] you would delete the duplicate from which ever object you wish.

edit: sorry for not actually posting any code
you'd probably want a nested loop like so...

```
 for i in object1:
   for x in object2:
  *check and delete if needed here*
```

i'm new to stack overflow and am having a hard time indenting this correctly :p

extra edit: i really just skimmed your question and didn't realize you were dealing with only one object. i thought maybe you had two objects, but this approach might work if you make a duplicate of the origional object

Comment: It must be a harder task than I thought. Thank you for your consideration! :)